# Does The Rivan Codex add anything to the storyline of the Belgariad?

Tags: david-eddings, the-belgariad

I've been a long time fan of the Belgariad series by David Eddings, including the Malloreon sequel series, and have also bought and read the follow-up "prequels", Belgarath and Polgara.
Another book exists, "The Rivan Codex", which I get the impression is simply a collection of draft work and fleshing out of religions and cultures; and thus, I have never gotten around to buying or reading it.

So my question is, does it add anything to the storyline in the same way that the Belgarath and Polgara books do, or is it more of a reference book?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It has a lot of background material like DVD extras.
It's written very much in the style of the Prologues and Belgarath and Polgara. There's a bunch of information that's not contained in the rest of the series.
For instance, it starts with a section talking about how the world was created.
What it also has, which is quite interesting is the original story Eddings wrote which details Belgarath's history.
And the last section has some more information about what happens next after the conclusion of Polgara.

I enjoyed it.

Answer (score 8):

It is a reference book. It's interesting in a few details like the expansion of details of the Tolnedran Empire, but only buy it if you're the type to buy the Star Trek Technical Manual.

I checked it out of the library, but felt no compulsion to buy it.

Comment: Wow, the same answer within about 5 seconds of each other... Sigh.

Answer (score 8):

[The Rivan Codex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rivan_Codex) is a collection of background material. Think about a DVD that includes information about the making of the movie, and you'll get a pretty good idea about what this book is about. It does have some interesting insights, but it's probably not something you would read over and over again. Check it out from a library, or something similar, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The Rivan Codex also contains the Mallorean Gospels, which are not reproduced in any other book, not even snippets or excerpts of it.

In the final chapter, David Eddings explains the methodology which he employs to create written works of fiction. I can surmise that the Rivan Codex is meant to give the reader an insight into the depth and quality of material that must first be created even before an author can begin to write the actual book(s).

Comment: Agree adds more to the Malloreon than the Belgariad and gives background to the development of the Belgariad to its final form. Very much like the appendices to the Lord of the Rings and Christopher Tolkien's other works to bring us the background.